# SELECT returning no rows using declared variable inside MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, where-clause

I am trying to perform an INSERT...SELECT to create rows in a 'tasks' table once a row is created in a 'workflow' table. (The process_index used in the workflow creation looks up those tasks required in the 'process_tasks' table then creates them in the tasks table).

The problem, however, is that after performing an insert with the process_index of 'process_one' on the workflow table, the SELECT in the trigger finds no rows. I considered that the @process_id was not being set properly, but with the alternative insert i've commented out in the trigger, it demonstrates that the @process_index is being set correctly. Can anyone advise?

Here is some simplified code to demonstrate the problem:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS workflow;
CREATE TABLE workflow (
  id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  process_index VARCHAR(12)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tasks;
CREATE TABLE tasks (
  id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  process_index_used VARCHAR(12),
  target_field VARCHAR(12)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS process_tasks;
CREATE TABLE process_tasks (
  id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  process_index VARCHAR(12),
  source_field VARCHAR(12)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO process_tasks SET process_index = 'process_one', source_field = 'alpha';
INSERT INTO process_tasks SET process_index = 'process_one', source_field = 'beta';

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS workflow_tasks;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER workflow_tasks AFTER INSERT ON workflow
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE process_index VARCHAR(12);
  SET @process_index = NEW.process_index;
--  INSERT INTO tasks (process_index_used) VALUES (@process_index);
  INSERT INTO tasks (target_field) SELECT source_field FROM process_tasks WHERE process_index = @process_index;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: If the `@process_index` is set properly and your `SELECT source_field FROM process_tasks WHERE process_index = @process_index;` returns no rows, that can mean only one thing. Did you check if you had records for that index in your `process_tasks` table?

Comment: Hi - there are definitely rows in the process_tasks table (as per the two inserts in the block code).